# Problems running CMake

Tags: cmake

I am having some problems running cmake. I installed cmake using homebrew. I also have reinstalled it, however, it keeps giving me errors. How can I fix it? 
Thank you!

```
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: CMakeDetermineGeneratorCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_Generator_COMPILER_ENV_VAR
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_Generator_COMPILER
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file:CMakeFiles/3.13.4/CMakeGeneratorCompiler.cmake
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  No CMAKE_Generator_COMPILER could be found.
 Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting the CMake cache entry
 CMAKE_Generator_COMPILER to the full path to the compiler, or to the
  compiler name if it is in the PATH.
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: CMakeGeneratorInformation.cmake
CMake Error: CMAKE_Generator_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.13.4)
project (Password Generator)

set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Werror -std=c++14")
set (source_dir "${PROJECT_SRC_DIR}/src/")

file (GLOB source_files "$source_dir/*.cpp")

add_executable(
    Password Generator
    ${source_files}
)
```

Comment: I guess `$source_dir` should be `${source_dir}`?

Comment: With `project (Password Generator)` you actually assign `Password` as a project name and request "Generator" language support, which is obviously not what you expect. It is better to not use space in the project's name. E.g., use `project (Password_Generator)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your incorrect invocation of the `project` command:

```
project (Password Generator)
```

This sets `Password` as the name of your project and specifies that it only uses one programming language named `Generator` (which of course CMake doesn't support).

You should make your project name something that would be a valid C identifier, e.g.:

```
project(PasswordGenerator)
```